# algorithm to find the order to visit nodes of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

i have a graph with a start node with each edge having a cost...i need an algorithm to find the order in which i have to visit ALL these nodes so that the total distance i traversed is least ... Pls suggest an algo for this...

Comment: What role does the cost play?

Comment: And ... what graph algorithms did you already learn in class?

Comment: I suggest http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling_salesman_problem), or a close variant, albeit constrained if the graph is not complete.

Comment: How can you say that? The OP didn't tell us the role of the edge costs and dis not say that he is looking for a Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: i need to visit all the nodes exactly once... also,the cost of edges represent the distance between the vertices... I need to visit all the nodes so that the distance traveled is least .... Sounds like a travelling sales man problem only

Comment: Why do you say "only"? TSP is hard, really hard.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know something about the graph structure, you are dealing with a so-called NP complete problem. For the general problem (without constraints) there aren't even satisfactory heuristics for finding approximate solutions.

The problem is indeed the travelling salesperson problem and so far, only brute force trying of all paths is an algorithm that guarantees to find the best path, but it's impractical for larger graphs.

Comment: Brute force would give you an O(n!) algorithm, whereas there are known O(n^2 2^n) dynamic-programming based algorithms as well.

Comment: Yep, but then you need some bound on the edge costs, don't you?

Comment: How do you know that? The question is not fully specified.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use modified [A* Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm). Normally you will start from X and end when reach Y. In modified version you do not stop when reach some node Y but when you have visited all nodes. Note also that if some node was visited it is pointless to travel to it from another node, that should do the thing.